# Bug while trying to get the size of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm using Vue. I have a div which look like this:

```
<div :style="'width:' + imageSize.width + 'px; height:' + imageSize.height + 'px'" id="image-container"></div>
```

The dimension are stored in my data like this:

```
data() {
return {
  ...
  imageSize: {
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  }
  ...
}
```

Also I have two buttons to zoom in and out the div:

```
<v-btn rounded color="white" class="ma-2" @click="zoom('+')">
   <v-icon>mdi-magnify-plus-outline</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<v-btn rounded color="white" class="ma-2" @click="zoom('-')">
  <v-icon>mdi-magnify-minus-outline</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

The zoom's function look like this:

```
zoom(type) {
  if(type == '+') {
     this.imageSize.height += 100;
     this.imageSize.width += 100;
     console.log('Zoom in clicked!')
  } else {
     this.imageSize.height -= 100;
     this.imageSize.width -= 100;
     console.log('Zoom out clicked!')
  }
  const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = document.getElementById("image-container");
  console.log(offsetWidth);
  console.log(offsetHeight);
},
```

When I click the button to zoom in the div everything works and the size of the div increases by 100px per side.
But when I get the size of the div (which I need to save in the data) the size stays the same. Also I noticed that if I click again I get the previous zoom size.
Here is the screenshot of the console:
[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGfTN.png)

When i get 500 i should get 600 and so on.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = document.getElementById("image-container");
  console.log(offsetWidth);
  console.log(offsetHeight);
}, 100)
```

try this after the if else block.

This happend to me 2 days ago while animating with gsap.
My guess is, by the time the image.height or image.width changes the other statements runs before it , ie it took time to change it.

I tried this and in my case it worked.